# Aligning Text in Fixed footer With Container

Tags: html, css, sass, containers, fixed

I'm trying to align the text in my fixed footer with the left edge of the site container, rather than the left edge of the footer. The footer is absolutely positioned at 0px at the left and bottom.

Here is my Sass code:

```
#neo_container {background: #000; width: 960px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }

#neo_footer_container { 
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 35px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10000;
        background: #666;
        color: #FFF;

        .neo_footertext{float: left; margin-right: 400px; font: 11pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} /* Formatting for copyright text in fixed footer */
        .neo_footertext2{font: 11pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}  /* Formatting for Neoscape text in fixed footer */

    }
```

The HTML and CSS can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/maW8E/

Comment: you want to allign .neo_footertext - class next to neo_container ?

Comment: I need to align the text in #neo_footercontainer (fixed footer) with the left edge of #neo_container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't adverse to altering your HTML a little, you could add an internal wrapper that has a same width as the container you're trying to align to. So you HTML for the footer could look like (note addition of `.inner-wrap` around contents:

```
<div id="neo_footer_container">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <p class="neo_footertext">469 SEVENTH AVE NEW YORK NY 10018 Privacy Policy | Legal Statement | Disclaimer</p>
        <p class="neo_footertext2">Designed by Neoscape</p>
        <!--Placeholder for 'Designed by Neoscape' logo-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, removing both of these CSS styles on `.neo_footertext`:

```
#neo_wrapper .neo_container #neo_footer_container .neo_footertext {
    float:left;
    margin-right:400px;
}
```

And adding these ones to style `.inner-wrap`:

```
#neo_wrapper .neo_container #neo_footer_container .inner-wrap{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Now, you should end up with an internal container of the same width as `#neo_wrapper`, centered within the `#neo_footer_container` - so your footer content will remain aligned to the edge of your main content wrapper.

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maW8E/2/) to demonstrate the code working.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, works fine. I tried doing something similar earlier but didn't have the width set to 960px

Comment: Great, glad I could help out! Don't forget to accept an answer if it properly solves your question (click the checkmark outline beside the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here: Remove float: left

```
 .neo_footertext{
   float: left;  //Remove this
   margin-right: 400px; // I would also remove this, unless you have a reason to put it in.
}
```